# GroupBy and Sum with a RangeIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm reading in a CSV with wide data, which I convert to long data. The data contains daily values for all of 2020. I'm trying to aggregate this by month and sum. This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Notebooks/updated_predicted_data.csv', parse_dates=['Unnamed: 0'])
df.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'yyyy_mm_dd'}, inplace=True)
df = df.melt(id_vars=['yyyy_mm_dd'])
df.rename(columns={'variable': 'name'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'value': 'predicted_value'}, inplace=True)

df['predicted_value'] = df['predicted_value'].str.replace('€', '')
df['predicted_value'] = df['predicted_value'].str.replace(',', '')
df['predicted_value'] = df['predicted_value'].astype(int)

df.dtypes

yyyy_mm_dd       datetime64[ns]
name             object
predicted_ttv    int64
dtype:           object
```

All of the above works fine, when I then try to group the data, I run into the issue:

```
sum_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

How come I get the above error, despite converting my date column from string to datetime and also predicted column from string to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `key` parameter in [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for pass column name of datetimes with `name` column in list and added aggregation function `sum`:

```
sum_df = (df.groupby(['name',pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='yyyy_mm_dd')])['predicted_ttv']
           .sum()
           .reset_index())
```

Or convert `yyyy_mm_dd` to `DatetimeIndex` first:

```
sum_df = (df.set_index('yyyy_mm_dd')
            .groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])['predicted_ttv']
            .sum()
            .reset_index())
```

Comment: Could I specify a second key so the data is grouped by both `yyyy_mm_dd` and `name` before being summed? Also, this outputs `<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object`, how could I get this back to be a regular pandas dataframe?